# VSCode Folders Not Sorting Alphabetically

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code Explorer pane is sorting my folders oddly. I want to validate this is truly an issue before reporting it as a bug. I have vscode 1.47.2. I'm fairly sure this wasn't always an issue. Here's an example:

[image: VSCode Explorer Screenshot]

I would expect that a folder named "aaa.xxx.iii" would be alphabetically sorted before the folder named "aaa.yyy". In fact, when I look at the list in File Explorer, it is indeed sorted correctly.

I am not using a workspace file. I have searched the entire directory structure and I have no files suffixed with .code-workspace. I know this can be an issue in multi-root workspaces. However, I am just using "Open Folder" to open this solution.

I have also checked the settings under Workspace Settings, Features, Explorer, Sort and it is set to default (Alphabetic, Folders before Files). I tried changing to Modified sort order and back with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

> I would expect that a folder named "aaa.xxx.iii" would be alphabetically sorted before the folder named "aaa.yyy"

It is alphabetically sorted, just ASCII sorted!

ASCII values:

```
a = 97
b = 98
i = 105
x = 120
y = 121
. = 46
```

Therefore:

```
aaa         = 291
aaa.xxx     = 697
aaa.yyy     = 700
aaa.xxx.iii = 1,012
```

However, there seems to be some variation to their logic. They actually split filenames via a filename regex (and they use the same logic for comparing directories and filenames). They effectively compare against a filename first, before even considering the extension using the following regex:

```
const FileNameMatch = /^(.*?)(\.([^.]*))?$/;
```

And then it will only consider extensions when it returns `0`, for not greater than or less than.

Using that regex: in your example, `aaa.xxx`, `aaa` is the filename, `.xxx` is the 'extension`.

With `aaa.yyy`; `aaa` is the filename and compared against `aaa.xxx.iii`, you get it `.iii` is the extension. Ergo, `aaa.yyy`, or the name without the `.yyy` extension: `aaa` < `aaa.xxx` or `aaa.xxx.iii` with the extension

Here is their logic:

[explorerViewer.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/492b96a860376d32a7c7f707c60999d2afe5ca21/src/vs/workbench/contrib/files/browser/views/explorerViewer.ts#L631-L715)

[comparers.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/492b96a860376d32a7c7f707c60999d2afe5ca21/src/vs/base/common/comparers.ts#L53-L78):

```js
export function compareFileNamesNumeric(one: string | null, other: string | null): number {
    const [oneName, oneExtension] = extractNameAndExtension(one, true);
    const [otherName, otherExtension] = extractNameAndExtension(other, true);
    const collatorNumeric = intlFileNameCollatorNumeric.value.collator;
    const collatorNumericCaseInsensitive = intlFileNameCollatorNumericCaseInsenstive.value.collator;
    let result;

    // Check for name differences, comparing numbers numerically instead of alphabetically.
    result = compareAndDisambiguateByLength(collatorNumeric, oneName, otherName);
    if (result !== 0) {
        return result;
    }

    // Check for case insensitive extension differences, comparing numbers numerically instead of alphabetically.
    result = compareAndDisambiguateByLength(collatorNumericCaseInsensitive, oneExtension, otherExtension);
    if (result !== 0) {
        return result;
    }

    // Disambiguate the extension case if needed.
    if (oneExtension !== otherExtension) {
        return collatorNumeric.compare(oneExtension, otherExtension);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So it appears, for the most part, they are just using [Intl.Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator) with basic name value `a < b` logic, with some variations of course.

It also appears they disambiguate by length, meaning `foo1` and `foo01` are considered equal. [line 169](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/492b96a860376d32a7c7f707c60999d2afe5ca21/src/vs/base/common/comparers.ts#L169-L183)

---

#### Settings

The setting you described only affects 'how they are displayed', in a way sorted yes, but mostly how they are shown to the user, not really how they are sorted programmatically as I interpret it.

> // Controls sorting order of files and folders in the explorer.
>
> //  - default: Files and folders are sorted by their names, in alphabetical order. Folders are displayed before files.
>
> //  - mixed: Files and folders are sorted by their names, in alphabetical order. Files are interwoven with folders.
>
> //  - filesFirst: Files and folders are sorted by their names, in alphabetical order. Files are displayed before folders.
>
> //  - type: Files and folders are sorted by their extensions, in alphabetical order. Folders are displayed before files.
>
> //  - modified: Files and folders are sorted by last modified date, in descending order. Folders are displayed before files.
>
> "explorer.sortOrder": "default",

So it's more of a presentation setting for files/directories not the names themselves.
If you look at the `explorerViewer.ts` control flow you will see:

```js
  switch (sortOrder) {
    case 'type':
    if (statA.isDirectory && !statB.isDirectory) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (statB.isDirectory && !statA.isDirectory) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (statA.isDirectory && statB.isDirectory) {
        return compareFileNamesNumeric(statA.name, statB.name);
    }

    break;
```

And now we can visualize going back to how directories are sorted with the same function; re `if (statA.isDirectory && statB.isDirectory)`

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is an outstanding issue. I changed my search terms on GitHub and found the original discussion. It seems there's no resolution as of this comment.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99955

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the "Sort Order Lexicographic Options" setting and set it to `unicode` to get the desired results.