# Why does VS Code Explorer sort files differently from Windows Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to get VS Code to sort the files and directories the same way the Windows Explorer does?

I have tried changing the user setting `Features > Explorer > Sort Order`, but that has no option to sort it "normally" or how I would like it to do (i.e. as Windows Explorer does).

Look at the subtle difference between VS Code (left) vs Windows Explorer (right).

[image: Sort order in Visual Studio Code File Explorer]
[image: Sort order in Windows Explorer]

I would expect directories that start with the same string to be sorted next to each other, but the dot seems to confuse the Explorer.

Is there a way to change this behaviour? Or is there a very good reason the VS Code team chose to do this?

Comment: It has been explained here some time ago. It has to do with the sorting of files without extension (part after the last dot). https://stackoverflow.com/a/62976037/9938317

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to search for this but was not able to find it. I will be following the progress of https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99955 then.